# Vite and SvelteKit - Using multiple entry html files

Tags: vite, sveltekit

I am just starting to get into SvelteKit and have a question regarding development and builds.

I am using the static adapter and I would like to have two entry points for my SvelteKit app.

One being the default index.html (src/app.html) and the other being other.html (other/app.html).

eg.

```
build
    ...
    index.html
    other.html
src
    ...
    app.html
other
    ...
    app.html
```

Is there a way using Vite or SvelteKit to have these two separate entries in the one build configuration?

Comment: That just mean two different routes isn’t it? What’s the difference?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. But if I used routes, it is using the same entry in Vite. My specific use case requires two entries. I understand, that this may not be possible.

Comment: It’s possible. Multi-entry in vite is handled by rollup, the actual bundler under the hood. You can pass entry options directly to rollup.

Comment: But my question is, wouldn’t static-adapter, after build, just give you two html files already if you have two routes, without any further config?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, static adapter will give me the html files if I create the routes. But this is a particular use case that requires two entries, regardless of the output. Thanks for your suggestion with rollup, I have tried this and sveltekit plugin overrides this option.

Comment: Eh, two html files IMO are two entries, I’m sorry I fail to get your point. What am I missing here?

Comment: I sense an AB problem here, when you think you need A in order to get B done, but never actually tell people what B is, which is your real problem, and could possibly be solved without involving A. So what is your real problem?

Comment: No probs. It is complicated, it is not a standard web build and I was hoping that there was an answer to my OP without having to confuse the question with other details. It seems that this is not possible so I may have to find another solution. Thanks again for your help.